# Can you tell me where im messing up?

Tags: javascript

"You are given two digit integer n. Return the sum of its digits"

**Input/Output Details:**

- [time limit] 4000ms (js)
- [input] integer n
- A positive two-digit integer.
- Constraints: 10 ≤ n ≤ 99.
- [output] integer
- The sum of the first and second digits of the input number.

This is what im trying

```js
function addTwoDigits(n) {
    var string = n.toString();

    var sum = parseInt(string.charAt(0)) + parseInt(string.charAt(1));
    return sum;
}
```

```js
var userInput = prompt('20');

if (userInput >= 10 && userInput <= 99) {
    console.log(addTwoDigits(userInput));
}
```

Comment: The implementation of `addTwoDigits` looks correct to me.  What is the expected behavior and what is the actual behavior?  What exactly is "not working"?  Are there any errors thrown?

Comment: I don't think there is anything wrong with your code. If you are expecting it to add up the individual digits of the number it is doing exactly that. It is possible to make it more efficient e.g. `Math.floor(n / 10) + (n % 10)`. Although this would not work if `n` was a string.

Comment: Also you can make a [more general version](https://ideone.com/HyVCS2) that works for any number of digits.

Comment: @AlexanderNied there’s 10 test it’s supposed to pass just using different numbers, for example the first test wants an “input n:29” “expected output 11”. I used “var userInput =prompt(‘29’); . The output comes back  “undefined” and console Output comes back “empty”

Comment: @AlexanderNied I also have screenshots of it